# Thermal pad thickness

Tags: heat, heatsink, thermal

We are going to use GAP PAD HC 5.0 thermal pad to transfer the heat from a FPGA (XCKU040) to a heatsink. My question is regarding the thickness I should choose to obtain best performance.

On the one side, I understand that lower thickness = lower thermal resistance = higher heat transfer. On the other side, higher thickness allows it to absorb more deformations in the chip / heatsink surface, but it is worse in terms of heat transfer.

Is this correct? Any more ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Doesn't seem right.  Thicker metal does not mean deformation to irregularities, nor higher thermal resistance

Comment: @ScottSeidman he's talking about the malleable stick-on thermally-conductive pad to connect the FPGA to the heatsink.

Comment: The thermal pad material is fiberglass, not metal.

Comment: Which thickness did you go with?

Comment: Just a pedant-point, @ScottSeidman - if all other characteristics remain constant any increase in a thermal path length will increase its thermal resistance; the increase will be infinitesimal when that dimension is smaller by orders of magnitude than the others, but increase it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that chip I'd go with the thinnest 20 mil.
The case is so smooth if they had a thinner one I'd use that.
The case top surface does not appear to deviate more than 1 mil.
I guess that's the quality you get when you pay over $2,000 for a chip.

I like the thermal pad you selected.  Good choice.

[image]

---

> On the other side, higher thickness allows it to absorb more
>   deformations in the chip / heatsink surface, but it is worse in terms
>   of heat transfer.

Yes, thicker is worse in terms of heat transfer.
Doubling the pad thickness doubles the thermal resistance.

[image]
Source: [Gap Pad 5000S35 datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/48/TDS_GP_HC%205_0616%20v3-1079679.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct.

It is unlikely that the surface of a chip or of a heatsink would be so rough that much needs to be taken up by a pad.

Where you might need to use a thicker pad is if you are using one heatsink for several components and some of those components have a different height, and the thermal dissipation does not warrant the cost of machining the base of the heatsink to varying heights. For example, on a PC GPU card.

Comment: @Downvoter It would be helpful if you could let us know what is wrong or incomplete in that answer. Then I can make corrections or delete it as appropriate.

Comment: I do not down vote, but you did not answer the question: Which thickness?  And your comments about multiple chips was kinda lame.

Comment: He was pretty clear thickness vs. thermal resistance (e.g "it is worse in terms of heat transfer").  And "My question is regarding the thickness I should choose".  The GAP PAD HC 5.0 comes in 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, and 125 mil thicknesses.  Like I said I would not down vote and you asked.

Comment: Sorry, I take it back. You did answer the question "Is this correct?"  I interpreted it as which thickness should be used.  And I  read "it is worse" as "is it"